# Why map() is not working for 1 column instead it is working for multiple columns

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to perform column transformation using map().
However, it is not working for 1 column as below : -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

data = [('James','Smith','M',30),
  ('Anna','Rose','F',41),
  ('Robert','Williams','M',62)]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema = columns)
rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: 
    (x["firstname"]+","+ x["lastname"])
    )  
df2=rdd2.toDF(["fullname"])
df2.show()
```

It is showing TypeError

[image: Error Message]

The same query is working for multiple columns as below : -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

data = [('James','Smith','M',30),
  ('Anna','Rose','F',41),
  ('Robert','Williams','M',62)]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema = columns)
rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: 
    (x["firstname"]+","+ x["lastname"],x["gender"])
    )  
df2=rdd2.toDF(["fullname","gender"])
```

Output of above code is below : -

[image: Output with multiple columns]

So, I want to understand why map() is not working with 1 column but working with multiple columns.
What is the error in the 1st code that is returning TypeError ?

I can see the error is happening while trying to convert rdd to dataframe. Please check and let me know.

Thank you

Comment: just add a comma (`,`) between `x["lastname"]` and `)`. -- final expression - `(x["firstname"]+","+ x["lastname"],)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toDF()` expects a tuple of values but when you pass a single column it is just a string and infer schema will complain. The `_infer_schema` code looks something like:

```py
   if isinstance(row, dict):
# ...
    elif isinstance(row, (tuple, list)):
# ...
    elif hasattr(row, "__dict__"):  # object    
# ...
else:
        raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
```

To fix this add a trailing comma when you only have a single column, this will convert it into a tuple:

```py
rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: 
    (x["firstname"]+","+ x["lastname"],)
    )
```

This will help you understand better:

```py
>>> print(type(("hello")))
<class 'str'>
>>> print(type(("hello",)))
<class 'tuple'>
```

Now it will print:

```
+---------------+                                                               
|       fullname|
+---------------+
|    James,Smith|
|      Anna,Rose|
|Robert,Williams|
+---------------+
```